# Verifying $\mathbb T$ a subgroup of the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, multiplicative-function

Question: Let $\mathbb T$={$z\in$ $\mathbb Z$ :$\vert z\vert$=$1$}.
 Verify $\mathbb T$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of non-zero complex numbers?
I do not know what this type of $\mathbb T$ actually means so I am not understanding the problem. I have never encountered a question like this. Need some help

Comment: You're saying you don't understand what the set $\Bbb T$ is?

Comment: I never seen that symbol in math

Comment: That's OK, they're telling you what it stands for here: they're *defining* $\Bbb T$ to be the set of complex numbers with modulus $1$.

Comment: @behold: You know the definition of "group" and "subgroup", right? If so, simply verify that the given set is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers.

Comment: yeah. I know that. Thanks

Comment: That notation $\mathbb{T}$ is not a standard one that I'm aware of, but for now, it's just being used for the exercise, that's all. Perhaps the notation will continue to be used in your course, or maybe it was just a temporary notation, used just for the exercise. You'll find out.

Comment: The notation $\mathbb T$ is standard for the torus, of which $\{z\in\mathbb C\,:\,|z|=1\}$ is one possible formulation (another being $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that that should be $\mathbb{C}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}$. If so the given $z \in \mathbb{C}$, then $|z| = |a + bi| = \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}}$. Thus the question is asking you to show that such a set with $|z| = 1 \implies \sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} = 1 \implies a^{2} + b^{2} = 1$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ under multiplication. Thus you must show that the identity is in $\mathbb{T}$, that for all $a, b \in \mathbb{T}, ab \in \mathbb{T}$ and for all $a \in \mathbb{T}$      $ \exists a^{-1} \in \mathbb{T}$ such that $aa^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: You may be right but my question does have a $\mathbb Z$ in it. With my $\mathbb Z$, will be the same method as your answer or a different method?

Comment: Yes, the process is the same so everything will still work!

Comment: I would not say "the process is the same" - if $\mathbb Z$ was not a typo, the set in question is simply $\{-1,+1\}$, which is trivially a multiplicative group, but is not a *sub*group since $\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ is not a multiplicative group at all.